# Problem returning vector from a function

Tags: c++, stl, vector

error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token

Relevant section of C++ code:

```
InputParser::vector<bar*> getFooBar(){
return bars;
}
```

We have defined vector bars; as a private variable in the header file.

Can someone please explain how to resolve this error?

Comment: where is the rest of the code?

Comment: What you think is relevant and what is actually relevant are often two very different things, especially in cases where you are here precisely because you do not understand the problem. This is one of those times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is not too clear. If this is supposed to be a `std::vector`, that's not the type you are using. Assuming `getFooBar` is a member of `InputParser`, the syntax is:

```
std::vector<bar*> InputParser::getFooBar()
{
    return bars;
}
```

Comment: No problem. I suggest getting a decent book and brushing up on the declaration and definition of class members. :)

Comment: @VJo: Thanks! I practise on IRC ;P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to wrtie this :

```
const std::vector<bar*>& InputParser::getFooBar()
```